# SQL Redistribution Logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I have modified the query based on the requirements of this group. **There is a create and insert table query at the bottom of this post to help create the required table**. The expected result is also given in a screenshot to help understand. Request help on the same

Please help me out in this problem I have a **set of groups**, each of which have a **set of product**. Each **product** has a **total capacity** and a **original value**. There is a **table 2** which has a **Entitlement Value** for **each Group** of **Table 1**. The problem statement is

- Scenario 1:If the sum of the **Original Values** of the **Products** in a **group** in **Table 1** is less than the **Entitlement Value** for that **group** in **Table2**. Then the following will happen - Increments of 10000 will be added to the **Products of the group**(in descending order of Original Value and Product number) till the **sum of the group** adds up to the **entitlement value** of **table 2**. However a **Product** can only fill till its **Capacity** is reached
- Scenario 2:If the **sum of the Original Values of the Products** in a **group** in **Table 1** is more than the **Entitlement Value** for that **group** in **Table2**.Then the following will happen - Decrements of 10000 will be reduced to the **Products of the group**(in descending order of Original Value and Product Number) till the **sum of the group** adds up to the **entitlement value** of **table 2**. However a **Product** can only fill till its **Original Value** has become 0
  **Note: For all the above calculation only those Products will be considered which has a positive Original Value**

[image]

```
USE [retaildb] --Use your database name
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_1](
    [Group] [varchar] NOT NULL,
    [Product] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [capacity] [bigint] NULL,
    [Original_Value] [bigint] NULL
)


insert into TABLE_1 values('A','1001',20000,10000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('A','1002',30000,20000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('A','1003',30000,10000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('A','1004',30000,20000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('B','1005',20000,10000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('B','1006',30000,20000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('B','1007',20000,20000)
insert into TABLE_1 values('B','1008',30000,30000)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_2](
    [Group] [varchar] NOT NULL,
    [Entitlement_Value] [bigint]
)

insert into TABLE_2 values('A',90000)
insert into TABLE_2 values('B',60000)
```

Comment: Seems like a bin-packing problem

Comment: Could you please help me write this?  Its very important for me

Comment: Could someone please help me out in this problem. I think it wont take much of your time , but will help me a lot